# Create a Capability category to group a few custom Capabilities

Tags: capabilities

The role editor has categories that allow easy grouping and finding of capabilities, how can I create a new one to add some of my own custom ones into?
[image]

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: WordPress doesn't group capabilities like this. The developer of whichever plugin you're using to manage them has done so themselves, so you would need to ask them how to make sure your custom capabilities appear in a particular place.